# How do I set up C/C++ on VSCode on MacOS (2019) properly?

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio-code

I am very VERY new to VSCode and C/C++, just started 10 mins ago, tried to follow the website tutorial for setting up c/c++ on VSC (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp#_intellisense) but the code I copied and pasted from the site wouldn't even run.  So I put some really simple code to try to see what the problem was.

I installed these extensions:
[screenshot of installed extensions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G97xi.png)

I think that I have set it up incorrectly somehow.

The code runs and outputs 'hello world', but there is a permanent red squiggle at the end and to my knowledge, I haven't missed any brackets.  Also, when I pasted the code from that link in, my text wasn't green for words like vector and string even though I used #include at the beginning.

Reminder that I am on MacOS (2019), and Xcode tools is installed

Main code (named helloworld.cpp):
[image: code as shown in VSCode]

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("hello,world\n");
}
```

**launch.json**

```
{

    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "clang++ - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "lldb",
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: clang++ build active file"
        }
    ]
}
```

**tasks.json**

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "clang++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/clang++",
            "args": [
                "-std=c++17",
                "-stdlib=libc++",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "C/C++: clang++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/clang++",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: what errors do you get? do you have the clang installed?

Comment: I think the intellisense setup is is `c_cpp_properties.json`

Comment: I'd recommend using a proper IDE (or just a basic text editor and compiling from the command line) over VSCode any day. It's not very beginner friendly and it's a rather complicated beast to use for C++. Visual Studio Community Edition, Qt Creator, XCode or just plain vim or Emacs would be better options (IMHO).

Comment: In C++, prefer `#include <cstdio>` over `#include <stdio.h>`.